# How can I share onTouch MotionEvent between two fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

[image: steps in application]

I have 2 fragments. First is running all the time (first screen). When I click and hold its `TextView` I add second fragment (second screen). Then still holding I'm dragging pointer at red TextView owned by second fragment (third screen). When I enter that red `TextView`, I want to increase its alpha value. Then when I do `ACTION_UP` second fragment destroys and clicked `TextView` in the first fragment disappears (fourth screen).

**My problem is how to manage onTouchListener in the second fragment on the red TextView?**

I tried to listen if `onTouchListener` in the second fragment even responses but it's not.

```
//second fragment
...
deleteTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            event = MotionEvent.obtainNoHistory(event);

            //here testing if onTouch works
            if(event.getAction()>=0) {
                Log.v("UWAGA ZOOM", Integer.toString(event.getAction()));
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER){
                deleteArea.setAlpha(1.0f);
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT){
                deleteArea.setAlpha(0.5f);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But onTouchListener responses from first fragment !

```
//first fragment
...
linearLayout2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            //here testing if onTouch works
            if(event.getAction()>=0) {
                Log.v("UWAGA", Integer.toString(event.getAction()));
                return true;
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Fragment dayEventZoomFragment = new DayEventZoomFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("event_title", dayEvent.getTitle());
                bundle.putInt("event_hour", dayEvent.getHour());
                dayEventZoomFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, dayEventZoomFragment, "dayEventZoomFragment").addToBackStack("fragmentDay")
                        .commit();
                return true;
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                getActivity().dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
                getActivity().dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

So when I drag pointer like in third ss, I get only LOG "UWAGA" and I don't get LOG "UWAGA ZOOM".
How to start listening events in the second fragment, when still holding finger on screen before the start that second event?